# Second-order Taylor Method Implementation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am currently working on implementing the second-order Taylor method in python to approximate the initial value problem:

> $x'(t) = \frac{e^t}{x(t)}$ where $t \in [0,1]$ such that $x(0) = 1$. Also note that the number of "time" steps required is $N = 4$ and in turn we have a step size of $h = \frac{1}{4} = 0.25.$

My approximation to $x(1)$ is $1.79455216$ whereas it should be in the ballpark of $2.102104$, I am at a loss at this point as to what is wrong with my implementation (pesky logic error, most likely). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np


def Euler(f, y0, t, df):  # make sure the first element of t is the initial t, t_{0}

    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    y[0] = y0  # the first element of this list is the initial condition y0, the last element is the numerical solutions

    for n in range(0, len(t) - 1):  # note the end point of range, so we don't throw an error
        y[n + 1] = y[n] + f(y[n], t[n]) * 0.25 + 0.03125 * df(y[n], t[n])

    return y  # we return the whole list since we would like to plot this approx for comparison.


g = lambda y, t: np.exp(t) / y
dg = lambda y, t: (np.exp(t) / y) * (1 - (np.exp(t) / y ** 2))
y0 = 1
t = [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75]  # found by using t_{n+1} = t_{n} + h
approx = Euler(g, y0, t, dg)

print(approx[-1])
```

Comment: Try making h smaller.

Comment: Also, your coefficients (,25 and .03125) should be functions of h so they will automatically adjust when h changes.

Comment: I wouldn't call the function "Euler"...

Comment: @PierreCarre - Oops! That was a mistake, thanks for catching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, you just need to add one more time step, since you are asked to do 4 steps, but `t=0` is not a step. So, just extend your vector `t` to be: `t = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]`

Here is the entire code again:

```
import numpy as np


def Euler(f, y0, t, df):  # make sure the first element of t is the initial t, t_{0}

    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    y[0] = y0  # the first element of this list is the initial condition y0, the last element is the numerical solutions

    for n in range(1, len(t)):  # note the end point of range, so we don't throw an error
        y[n] = y[n-1] + f(y[n-1], t[n-1]) * 0.25 + 0.03125 * df(y[n-1], t[n-1])

    return y  # we return the whole list since we would like to plot this approx for comparison.


g = lambda y, t: np.exp(t)/y
dg = lambda y, t: (np.exp(t)/y)*(1-(np.exp(t)/y**2))
y0 = 1
t = [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0]  # found by using t_{n+1} = t_{n} + h
approx = Euler(g, y0, t, dg)

print(approx)
```

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment)

If $xx'=e^t$,
$(x^2)'=2e^t,
x^2=2e^t+c,
x=\sqrt{2e^t+c}$.

If
$x(0)=1,
1=\sqrt{2+c},
c=-1,
x=\sqrt{2e^t-1},
x(1)=\sqrt{2e-1}
=2.1063...
$.